# Uploading a document upon demand

Tags: architecture

I am creating a logging system which will log errors to a remote server  from an user pc/client. occasionly we may need to get some ppt/doc files which will be  created by the user at the user pc/client for testing purpose. We will only need this file if we cannot solve the issue using the initial report sent by the logging system.

The admin of the logging system will be looking at a web based interface. He will call for the doc/ppt if there is an absolute necessary, only when the admin cannot fix the issue with the the text supplied by the logger. When the admin issues a request for the document, the user pc/client will upload the document to the server.

What is the best approach to do this. I mean how should the client responds to the request from the server. Do the client  have to rely on FTP upload?

Regards,

John

Answer (score 0):

You could share the folder where the local file is, that way the admin would have access.